# MCU signal isolated and Amplified (Optocoupler+BJT+Mosfet)

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, opto-isolator, isolation

I've com up with the following design.
I feel I've used too many components, don't know.
but I have some reasons for anything included in the design.

[image: Schematic]

- **PULSE_A** : some low frequency (50~1000Hz) low duty cycle pulse from MCU. (STM32F407)
- **R2** : limiting the MCU pin current (because there are around 20 such outputs, and the overall current sunk from MCU might get high)
- **R3** : to make sure Q5 turns off fast when pulse from MCU goes low. (necessary?)
- **U2** : optocoupler (have to use this exact part, which unfortunately inverses the input high/low)
- **R4** : limits the current to the IR LED inside the Optocoupler
- **U1** : an inverting Schmitt trigger logic IC (to make the output of the whole circuit in phase with the input)
- **R5** : Don't know if necessary, wanted to make sure there's nothing between HIGH\LOW states.
- **R6** : to limit the current from 74HC14 output
- **R7** : same as R3
- **Q6** : to charge the MOSFET gate (Q7)
- **R9** : to protect the MOSFET gate capacitor.
- **R8** : do discharge the MOSFET gate capacitor faster.
- **Q7** : the actual switch to R_LOAD. it's an N-Channel high power MOSFET, and its RDSon is rated @Vgs=8V in datasheet

**Question** : how to improve this? are resistor values valid?
I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to copy 20 series of these components for the rest of PULSE_B, PULSE_C etc. outputs.

Datasheets :

- [Q5 & Q6 : PZT2222A](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/PZT2222A_3-21816.pdf)
- [Q7 : IBP072N15](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPP075N15N3-DS-v02_06-en.pdf?fileId=db3a304319c6f18c0119cd76cc527ab6)
- [U2 : CYTLP521-GB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Qc4_lISrOdRc4Q68KAI-uJP2--EHA3u/view?usp=sharing)

**EDIT2**:
Based on comments, I changed my mistakes into this scheme :
[image: Updated scheme]
Can someone please confirm that the MCU is correctly isolated now ?

**EDIT3** :
Changed it a little more. grounds are the same again.
and added a resistor to the second BJT to limit it's Ic current to GND.
I know it's still flawed, cuz it's like the first scheme and I'm told it's not isolation (but didn't tell me what's wrong)
[image: Edit3]

with all respect and gratefulness toward all who read and answer or point me to some direction to learn sth, what's with this multi-level answering thing going on? tell me what's wrong about the isolation. you've told me the MCU pin is not isolated but why it isn't? I wouldn't ask a single question if I assumed the scheme to be working/flawless.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You say (in the schematic) that you want 24V pulses, but where are they going?  What are they driving?  Why do you need isolation?

Comment: What do you want to improve, what counts as an improvement? Half of the parts could be useless because what matters is you have a logic output with some specs and you need to drive the load with some specs, which are barely known. For example, the optoisolator does not isolate anything, why is it in the circuit? The FET would like more than 5V on gate but it is given less than 5V.

Comment: You really could just do this with a logic level MOSFET and a gate resistor but we need to know about the constraints you have.

Comment: @vir the loads are large inductive coils. The protection parts, against back EMI are done. That's why I didn't include them in the schematic. Voltage of some of these coils are around 80V. So I thought  isolation is more serious here. Using a single logiclevel mosfet isn't risky here?

Comment: @justme I'm providing around 8 volts to charge the mosfet gate. From a 9v rail. And by improvement I mean ommiting unnecessary parts, while still making sure mcu is well isolated from hogh voltage levels at load side. Or even suggest me another circuit, another method or practice

Comment: @Bikay Based on the schematics you are not providing 8V from a 9V rail. The transistor is driven as emitter follower, with presumably a 5V powered 74HC14. The resistive divider R6&R7 will drop that to 4.5V and after Vbe drop of Q6 it might be aroud 4V or a bit less.

Comment: @Bikay but your optoisolator isolates nothing according to your schematic. You can't just throw one in, connect the power and ground on both sides and think it's isolated. It's not - both sides are clearly connected according to your schematic.

Comment: On top of the other questions, when the MCU is in reset the load is likely energized continuously (assuming the drive circuit worked). Is that what you want?

Comment: @Justme thanks, yes my emmitter follower setup is mistake. I'll update it to be like the first BJT at the left side. (Common emmitter)

Comment: @MarcusMüller is it because of a common ground along the schematic? If so, again this is my mistake, but at drawing the schematic. The 24V load has a independent ground from the rest of circuit. I mean only the last ground (the one at right of all, below the MOSFET) is isolated from rest. Does it make my MCU pins correctly isolated?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thanks to mention, I know. Yes the momentary load current, while mcu resets is ok. The pin is configured as low immediately after reset. It has to be like this because I read somewhere it's better to invert the output of optoisolator, than to invert the MCU signal. (So that IR led is often off).

Comment: @Bikay So you changed only the output FET to some other ground? If so, now you can't turn it on, because you have no common ground reference with the circuit that is driving the FET gate. I also get that you used the opto to prevent MCU from burning up if the FET burns up, but where do you want to limit how much is allowed to burn up with the FET? If the FET burns up, it might push 24V via load to Q6 and U1 and through them to 9V and 5V supplies, and depending on the full schematics, the MCU might still burn with the rest of the board.Is it relevant that MCU survives when all other burns up?

Comment: oh god, then what should I do? how do I isolate the MCU pins from the rest of circuit and also isolate the high voltage zone from the low voltage zone when the MOSFET goes bad and makes short connections toward BJTs and MCU? please at least suggest me some keywords so I can search and read on the subjects.

Comment: @justme btw, in the second schematic, I also changed the way the second BJT switches. the problem with MOSFET gate not getting ~9V is solved here right ?

Comment: @Bikay The MOSFET gate won't be driven properly at all because FET Gate has 9V compared to BJT ground, but FET Gate does not have any defined voltage compared to FET Source which is undefined ground. And your BJT now just shorts 9V to ground directly and blows up.

Comment: If you need isolation, you need to have *separate power supplies* and *separate grounds* on each side of your optocoupler. So use the 9 V power supply for everything on the right, and don't connect the 9 V ground to the 5 V ground.

Comment: The optocouplers are not mythical isolation devices. They are simply a LED and a phototransistor in same package. While they **can** and **could** be used in a circuit for isolating two completely independent circuits from each other, your circuit uses same ground and same 5V supply on both sides of the optocoupler, so your circuit provides no isolation with the optocoupler. And you might not even need to or can't keep the supplies isolated. Now, the opto still provides an air gap between Q5 and 74HC14, but is there really need for that, and if it is, why?

Comment: If the MCU is connected to 24 MOSFETs and a serial port, it's simpler to isolate the serial port than the 24 MOSFETs. But do you actually need isolation?

Comment: @bobflux I'm actually worried about the MCU itself getting roasted. the loads are 24, 48, and 80 Volts, and they are 18 or 20 in quantity, purely inductive. I'm trying to make sure the protection procedures are the highest doable, even if it's overkill by some reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let's start from the right.

The MOSFET datasheet mentions a gate charge of Qg=40nC ; i=dq/dt so if you drive the gate with 1mA it will switch in 40µs (more or less). Your switching frequency is only 1kHz so you don't need to switch very fast to minimize switching losses (faster switching causes your wiring to radiate more noise).

But you say you want 1% duty cycle on a 1kHz period and that's a 10µs on-time, so if we want the MOSFET to reach full conduction before it turns of, then it should switch in less than a few µs. Let's go with 2µs, so we need 20mA gate drive.

The simplest solution would be to use MOSFETs with 5V gate drive, with one 74AC octal buffer like 74AC245 driving 8 MOSFETs with 5V. But since yours requires 9V this option is not available. Fortunately MMBT3904 costs 2 cents. Now back to your circuit.

If you want to switch inductive loads you need a freewheeling diode between the drain of your MOSFET and the positive supply. Otherwise when turning off the inductive load you'll get a voltage spike on the drain which will reach the avalanche breakdown of the MOSFET (~150V). The MOSFET is rated for this but it will absorb all the energy stored in the inductive load, so it may end up overheating, it depends on the load, frequency, etc. With a freewheeling diode it takes much longer for the current to fall but the inductive energy is mostly dissipated in the solenoid's internal resistance, and it is presumably bulky enough to withstand this.

I strongly disagree with the pullup R9. It's going to dissipate lots of power (0.81W per resistor on 9V, 20W for 24 resistors) all the time because it wants to turn the MOSFET ON and Q6 is preventing that. Also R10 is unnecessary, it prevents Q6 from being able to pull the MOSFET gate to ground, so it'll never turn off.

U1A is unnecessary: if you want to invert the output of an optocoupler, simply swap it with the pull resistor. So the 5V power supply on the isolated side also goes.

[image]

Here's a suggestion. I used a push pull driver (Q1 Q2) for the MOSFET to get decent gate current without wasting too much power in a pulldown resistor. R1 sets switching time. The current transfer ratio of your opto is pretty good so R3 can be increased a bit.

[image]

Note I've split the grounds, otherwise there is no isolation. If you join the grounds, then the optocouplers are useless, and the simplest solution is to drive the MOSFETs directly with a bunch of 74ACT245, the cheapest solution to get 8 channels voltage translation from 3.3V to 5V with >20mA output current.

Since 80VDC is involved, I feel some form of isolation is completely justified. Another option is to put a USB isolator on the programming cable that goes with the micro.

Comment: Thanks for corrections and suggestions. In your circuit, 1. could you please tell me what R8(3k3) and the one below it,(3k3 or 4k7) do? 2.can I use 3906 and 3904 for all BJTs used? and 3. Since the 9V rail is actually from battery, is it recommended (or possible at all) to split the 9v gnd from the loads side as well?

Comment: The mislabeled one (4k7) pulls the two transistor bases to ground when the opto is off. R8 limits base current of Q2 when the opto is on. 2. yes 3904 3906 are absolutely fine. 3. no you can't split the 9V from the loads because it's driving the MOSFETs and they're connected to the loads.

Comment: _"R8 limits base current of Q2 when the opto is on"_ by opto being on you mean the led is on or the phototransistor side conducting?  If I got it right, Q1 charges and Q2 discharges the MOSFET gate. Based on the Fig1 in the last page of optoisolator datasheet, in your suggested circuit, the mcu signal is reversed (i.e. duty cycle %99) on load side?

Comment: When MCU output goes to 3V3, Q3 conducts and lights the opto's LED at about 5mA. The phototransistor turns on and it conducts a current equal to the LED current multiplied by your opto coupler's current transfer ratio which is at least 130% from the datasheet, so we would get 6.5-30mA on the output transistor side of the opto. That doesn't happen because the two 3k3 resistors are too high value for that much current, but it forces the output of the opto to hit close to 9V. Then Q1 charges the MOSFET and turns it on. So the FET turns on if the MCU's output is high.

Comment: so as the last question, the phototransistor inside the optoisolator conducts when the IRLED is on ? (or as I supposed it's opposite, i.e. LED being on means Phototransistor being off) doesn't the picture in the datasheet show the operation being reversed as well ? (Fig1 page 3)

Comment: Yes the LED light turns the transistor on. So if you put the transistor between supply and output, when it's on, it pulls the output up and doesn't invert. If you put it between output and ground, when it's on it pulls the output down, so it inverts. In the datasheet the transistor is on the bottom, so it inverts, but you can use it the other way around too...