# Improving MOSFET switching timings (push-pull)

Tags: mosfet-driver, switching, gate-driving, push-pull

Based on my previous question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/690631/326609), as suggested I'm using a push-pull driver circuit to control a MOSFET gate.
this is the circuit:

[image: SCH]

And this is a simulation result:

[image: oscilloscope_simulated]

- Vertical Divisions are 1 V, Horizontal Divisions are ~7 uS.
- The yellow pulse is from the MCU (3.3 V, T.Rise = T.Fall = 100 nS).
- The blue curve is the optocoupler output. (Peaks at ~11.7 V).
- The red one is the voltage at output of push-pull transistors. (Vp:
  ~11.2 V).

The turn on is all ok (hopefully not just in simulation), but it takes around 60 uS for the gate voltage to fall to ~1 V. The turn off timing is important for the procedure I'm trying to follow. (Ideally to be less than 10 uS.)

**Question: How can the turn off times be shortened? (Which components are more effective here to adjust so the tail at turn off is less extended?)**

Answer (score 1):

Optocouplers with phototransistors have a (too) slow switch off time.

I would put a [Schmitt-Trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger) between the phototransistor and the MOSFET's Gate.

There are integrated circuits like the 40106 - or discrete possibilities with bipolar transistors etc. as well.

The Schmitt trigger decreases the drop time (and rise time) drastically.

Despite that, there will be a delay from the drop of the input signal until the MOSFET's Gate voltage changes, this cannot be eliminated. This is due to the slow switching off of any phototransistor.

Comment: It's spelled phototransistor in English, though I think most people will understand what you mean.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks, I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's summarise the switching speed as it now stands:
Turn on: delay is short, and Vgs rise time is fast, so all good.
Turn-off: delay is long, and Vgs fall time is slow, which needs improving.

Delay: defined as the time from input changing by 50% to output changing by 10%.
Based on the waveforms provided, it seems the delay time is about 0.5 divs, so:
Td(off) =0.5div x 7us/div = 3.5us.

This is much smaller than the total turn-off delay time, so I would ignore this for now.

Fall time: defined as the time taken for output to change from 10 % to 90%.  Based on the waveforms provided, it seems this is about 4.5 divisions, so:
4.5div x 7us/div = 31.5us.

To speed this up, try the following changes, then advise the new waveforms:
Change 1: R6: reduce from 200Ω to 22Ω.
Change 2: R4: reduce from 3k3 to 100Ω.
Change 3: R5: change from 3k3 to 1k.
Change 4: R7: New component, connected from Q2 base to Q2 emitter.  Value 470Ω.
Change 5: C1: New component, connected across R1.  Value 200pF.

There are other improvements that are possible, but these may not be required, it depends on what results you get after making the suggested changes.

Comment: I tried these changes in the suggested order.
1 and 2 didn't change the tail durance much. but reducing R5 helped a lot, now the gate voltage falls to 1V in 30uS after the MCU rise. that's 20uS after the MCU signal has fallen to Zero. about change4, you sure the resistor should be connected between base and emitter of the same BJT? doesn't it make the BJT switching operation bypassed ?

Comment: @Bikay  Change 4: this allows Vgs to discharge below the Vbe of Q3, but need to select R7 value low enough to get the benefit, but not too low that it "shorts out" the B-E of Q2 & Q3.  What is the MOSFET in your simulation?  What is the waveform of opto-coupler collector current?

Comment: Shorting B-E of Q2 and Q3 or just Q2? (Cuz you said to put the resistor on Q2, is it a typo or you meant that actually?). Mosfet will be IRBP072N15 (Ciss~5400pF) but the simulation is done using IRF064 (with Ciss~7000pF) i know the simulation will show slower timings, due to higher gate capacitance ( is this assumption right?) But thought the real world is gonna be a little slower than the simulations also.

Comment: R7 will connect across B-E of **both** Q2 and Q3.  That MOSFET (IRBP072N15) is quite large (150V 7.2mΩ), do you need such a large MOSFET?  What is the load?

Comment: There will be 10 of this circuit, each an output from MCU pin, controlling mosfets with very low duty cycle pulses (frequency is 50 to 1000Hz). Some of the loads are 24V, some are 36, and a few are 80V. All pure inductive loads. (The protections at load side are considered, that's why I didn't draw them at the schematics) that's why I've chosen such big mosfets to withstand possible back EMI from large coils. (And the grounds are also separated, and the 12V rails is from a buck converter from the same HV source that supplies the loads)

Comment: Back EMF from inductive loads causes voltage spikes, not current spikes.  Best handled by a diode to return the inductive current to the source.  Reducing the size of the MOSFET will result in lower Ciss and faster switching times for a given gate driver.   For a load fed from 24V & 36VDC supplies, a 150V MOSFET is overkill, a 60V MOSFET would be just fine.

Comment: well I went with this mosfet for its high V rating rather than its high current ratings.

Comment: May I suggest re-reading this part of my answer: "There are other improvements that are possible, but these may not be required, it depends on what results you get after making the suggested changes."   //For further assistance, please do the following:   1. Post the waveforms of the results after the changes.    2. What is the waveform of opto-coupler collector current?  3. Advise what the speed requirements are.

Comment: I don't know how to generate the "waveform of current" you asked for.  the timing requirements : the pulse from MCU is 3.3V (F=50Hz), and is high for 10uS. all I want is an isolated 24V pulse that is high for 10uS. it doesn't matter if the 24V pulse is delayed even up to hundreds of microseconds, as long as it's a pulse high for 10uS.

Comment: @Bikay  Was the waveform you presented in your OP generated by a simulation program?  If so, then it would be able to display the current of any component.   How close does the pulse duration have to be to 10us?

Comment: yes, it was from the simulation of Proteus. well if I fail to go with 10uS (which as far as I know is all because of the capacitance at the MOSFET part, rather than delays and timings inside ICs) then I'll try with 15uS. (which means 15uS pulses from MCU to control a MOSFET to be on for exactly 15uS). the procedure is such that the MCU generates a pulse, the MOSFET gets the pulse at gate, and when the gate voltage falls back to 1V (that I assume the MOSFET is off for sure) MCU starts to sample ADC conversions. the sampling continues until the next pulse is generated.

Comment: that's why the more time it takes for the gate voltage to fall down, the more samples are missed.

Comment: @Bikay  10us or 15us - Noted.  
//For further assistance, please do the following: 1. Post the waveforms of the results after the changes. 2. What is the waveform of opto-coupler collector current?